# React functional component vs. plain-old JS function that returns React element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I define a simple React functional component like this:

```
const Greeter1 = ({name}) => <h1>Hello {name}</h1>;
```

I can also define an equivalent plain-old JS function that returns a React element, like this:

```
const Greeter2 = name => <h1>Hello {name}</h1>;
```

The "React" version is of course also just a normal JS function, taking in a JS object instead of a string. We could use either of these functions within plain JS to get the greeter element for a given name, just with slightly different caller syntax:

```
const greeterElement1 = Greeter1({ name: "Bob" });
const greeterElement2 = Greeter2("Bob");
```

Within a React expression though, we can call these functions in a few different ways:

```
const someReact1 = <div>{ Greeter2("Bob") }</div>;
const someReact2 = <div>{ Greeter1({ name: "Bob" }) }</div>;
const someReact3 = <div><Greeter1 name="Bob" /></div>;
```

My question: Are there any effective differences between these calling styles other than syntax aesthetics? I assume `someReact1` and `someReact2` are virtually identical, but I'm not sure about `someReact3`. Does using the React component syntax change the way React treats things? Does it affect behavior or performance in any way? Or is it merely syntactic sugar?

When doing a diff on the virtual DOM tree, does React forgo comparing within a functional component if its attributes haven't changed between renderings? And if so, am I correct to assume that that optimization would be lost when calling functions directly as in `someReact1`?

I want to know b/c in some cases I actually prefer the style of `someReact1` as it allows me to use functional programming techniques like currying more easily, plus sometimes it's nice to not have to specify parameter names when calling. But am I paying some kind of penalty by doing so? Am I better off sticking with the traditional syntax?

Comment: I'm in the process of thinking more about this myself. So far, I've figured out that `<Greeter1 />` basically compiles to `React.createElement(Greeter1)` whereas the function calls embedded in JSX like `{Greeter1()}` do not really change when compiled. That's as far as I've gotten, but that's the real difference, I think. What effect that has on things I haven't yet figured out. They both render identical in the HTML tree. Not sure what they look like in React's virtual DOM.

Comment: There can also be unexpected differences in the way that things behave as a result of differences in the virtual DOM. This caused a layout-breaking CSS bug for me today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242769/react-material-ui-gridlisttile-looses-style-attributes-when-called-from-within/67242931#67242931

Answer (score 3):

Component functions are [(a bit?) faster](https://medium.com/@trueadm/in-react-16-functional-components-are-quite-a-bit-faster-than-class-components-1afca4931d7c) than class components since React 16. Not sure if it's true for prior versions.

Calling component function as a function is [much faster](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f) than calling it via JSX/`React.createElement`.
But, in most cases, this should not affect the way we write our code since JSX is pretty readable. To fill this gap we should use [@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements.html).

However, I understand your passion to call them as functions. For the sake of composition, I also find it quite useful. This is even more true for plain functions.
But, again, in the future, [functional components are going to have a state](https://twitter.com/sebmarkbage/status/658713924607606784). If it happens, we may regret our passion :)

Plain functions [seem to be faster](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/component-or-function-in-react) than component functions. However, I have not digged this topic yet. For example, I'm unsure if it works OK with `react-hot-reload`. Or, its pros/cons for performance and possible optimizations.

---

IMO, no matter the differences and in any case, **optimizations are still on us** - be it a `shouldComponentUpdate`, or memoization, or keys. Components which might not need any optimizations **should be** cheap to re-render, and vice versa (if it is a pure calculation, not DOM operation, obviously).

*Feel free to comment or correct, I'll update my post.*

Answer (score 0):

I found an explanation, apparently someone asked a similar question in a Github  issue on the official React repository. Here's a link to the issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16796 and an excerpt from the thread, an answer provided by a contributor:

> What I want to understand is this: Is it actually necessary to call
> React.createElement again, since it is already in the return value of
> the component? Is there any effective difference between that and
> calling the function component directly, like this?

As @hamlim mentioned, the effective difference is that simply calling a component as a function wouldn't work if the component was more complex than a pure function that returned another React element. React needs the element returned from `React.createElement` to handle those features.

> In the `HelloMessage` example you could technically just call it as a function, which would be equivalent to doing:
>
> ```
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <div>Hello Taylor</div>,
>   document.getElementById("hello-example")
> );
> ```
>
> This just inlines the result of `HelloMessage`, which would render the same UI in the browser. Thats effectively what you're doing by calling `HelloMessage` as a function. Internally this would be different to React since there's no component mounted, but practically speaking the behavior is identical in this trivial example.
>
> For the `ParentComponent` example, the same constraints apply. You *could* call the `ChildComponent` components as functions if they were just simple components without state or effects, and that would be the same result as just inlining their content into `ParentComponent`. In same cases this might be what you want, but typically not. If someone added state or effects to one of the `ChildComponent`s, or wrapped it in `React.memo` or `React.lazy`, this would break. So use this pattern with caution.