# React Component vs function, what should I use and why?

Tags: reactjs, function, components

Having those two examples in React in file user.js where User is the exported component

```
const displayText = (firstName, lastName) => (
  <div>{firstName} {lastName}</div>
)

const User = ({ user }) => (
  <div>
     You are logged in as 
     {displayText(user.firstName, user.lastName)}
  </div>
)
```

or

```
const DisplayText = ({ firstName, lastName }) => (
  <div>{firstName} {lastName}</div>
)

const User = ({ user }) => (
  <div>
     You are logged in as 
     <DisplayText firstName={user.firstName} lastName={user.lastName} />
  </div>
)
```

Which is better, faster or more recommended?

Later edit:
I added another example I see often and I cannot tell people why is wrong other than it looks a bit ugly

```
const User = ({ user }) => {
   const DisplayText = ({ firstName, lastName }) => (
     <div>{firstName} {lastName}</div>
   )

  return (
    <div>
     You are logged in as 
     <DisplayText firstName={user.firstName} lastName={user.lastName} />
    </div>
  )
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React functional components vs classical components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926574/react-functional-components-vs-classical-components)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use ES6 class based React components vs. functional ES6 React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965/when-to-use-es6-class-based-react-components-vs-functional-es6-react-components)

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in terms of performance. This just depends on how one want to call his component . In terms of syntax both are valid .

Comment: @MajidM. Ryan Lee Thanks for answers. There is no doubt when you introduce state, the only way is to use component.. but I wanted to find a reason why to not use the second approach, other than it looks ugly for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the React component compiled to React.createElement(component). While the function remains the same. I didn't feel find any performance issues using either of them (YET).

Some of the advantages of using the function itself is, that you can use the functional programming techniques like currying. Also, not naming the parameters while passing it in the function.

The only small downside of functions is, if you have more than 5 parameters, the order matters, and if you have to call the function somewhere, where only the 5th param needs to be passed, you have to pass the default params for the first four.

You might find this helpful as well.
[React functional component vs. plain-old JS function that returns React element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289275/react-functional-component-vs-plain-old-js-function-that-returns-react-element)

Comment: Thanks! Also there is this example I see often


const User = ({ user }) => {

const displayText = (firstName, lastName) => (
  <div>{firstName} {lastName}</div>
)

  return (
<div>
     You are logged in as 
     {displayText(user.firstName, user.lastName)}
  </div>
)
}